# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array, attributes

i'm getting this error in my code, how to remove it

my code ran into attribute error
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'open'
here's my code

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract 

camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _,Image=camera.read()
    cv2.imshow('Text detection',Image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF==ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('test1.jpg',Image)
        break
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def tesseract():
        path_to_tesseract = "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
        Imagepath='test1.jpg'
        pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=path_to_tesseract
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(Imagepath))
        print(text[:-1])
    tesseract()
```

Comment: `Image` happens to be a ndarray which doesn't have a method `.open`. Without more details, it's hard to help more. Please see [ask]

Comment: What is the purpose of using PIL here, other than providing yourself an opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot and wasting resources? OpenCV already has `imread` and pytesseract supports numpy arrays...

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a comma after the image:

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image,open(Imagepath))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You're overwriting your imported `Image` module symbol with a variable in

```
_,Image=camera.read()
```

Don't do that. Name it `image` or something; then `image.open` should be fine.